# MySQL "REPLACE INTO" using a SELECT to pull one field

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a MySQL database that has two tables (actually many more).  The first table links a product's SKU number to an arbitrary ID.  There is a second table that records the End of Day inventory for each item based on this ID.  When the inventory is changed for reasons OTHER than sales, there is a record placed in this second table with a Boolean set to false.  This allows me to say that this new number is not valid as a vector for sales previous, but is for the next day's sales.

There is some syntax error in this code.  I'm still a student, and would greatly appreciate the help in explaining how this kind of update would work.  I know the first value needs to come from the select statement?

Here is my current MySQL statement:

```
REPLACE INTO sales (`itemID`, `date`, `qty`, `price`) 
VALUES ([itemID], CURDATE(), [qty], 0.00) 
SELECT itemID FROM item WHERE `sku` = [sku]
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the statement.  I was hoping someone could tell me how to form the proper statement.  I've been bashing my head against the wall on this one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace works like insert, except that if there is a row with the same key you are trying to insert, it will be deleted on replace instead of giving you an error.

You can either specify arguments directly:

```
REPLACE INTO sales( `item_id`, `date`, `qty`, `price` )
VALUES( 15, '2012-01-01`, 5, '120.00' )
```

or specify them using SELECT:

```
REPLACE INTO sales( `item_id`, `date`, `qty`, `price` )
SELECT item_id, date, qty, price FROM sales_to_accept
WHERE sales_id = 721
```

You cannot however mix both types of syntax in one query.

But there is nothing stopping you from adding constant values as columns for the SELECT:

```
REPLACE INTO sales( `item_id`, `date`, `qty`, `price` )
SELECT item_id, CURDATE(), 5, '74.00' FROM item
WHERE `sku` = 'something'
```

Comment: A word of caution for future people who stumble across this.  REPLACE INTO causes all kinds of hell with AUTOINCREMENT.  This query is what I ended up using an INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with the above suggested option 3.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a replace into and a select in the same statement.
If you're trying to run this using a program of some sort or simply inputting it into MySQL, if you place a semi-colon after the `)` at the end of the values section, it will treat it as 2 separate requests.

If you're running this through PHP, then you'll need to break it up into 2 separate statements.

```
REPLACE INTO sales (`itemID`, `date`, `qty`, `price`) 
VALUES ((SELECT itemID FROM item WHERE `sku` = [sku]), CURDATE(), [qty], 0.00)
```

Comment: No this isn't my question.  I'm not trying to run to separate statements.  I'm trying to find the `itemID` in the `item` table that matches with the `sku` supplied.  Then replace the other properties of this `itemID` in the `sales` table.  This should be a single query.

Comment: So you're asking about a subselect, so see if that updated query works for you.